# transform translate ? añade margen o es relativo?

Tags: html, css, css3

El `transform translate` al usarlo mueve un elemento, ¿pero este funciona como el `position relative` utilizando  únicamente el espacio de la posición original? ¿O la posición es la nueva ?

Comment: explícate mejor , no entiende en concreto que es lo que deseas saber

Comment: al aplicar el transform translate, el espacio ocupado por el elemento es el original ? el original + margen ? o la nueva posicion sin amrgen ?

Comment: El original + margen.

Answer (score 1):

### posición: relativa

> Un elemento con `position: relative;` está posicionado en relación con su posición normal.
>
> Establecer las propiedades superior, derecha, inferior e izquierda de un elemento relativamente posicionado hará que se ajuste lejos de su posición normal. Otro contenido no se ajustará para caber en ningún espacio dejado por el elemento.

---

### translate()

> La función CSS re posiciona un elemento en las direcciones horizontal y / o vertical. Su resultado es un tipo de datos.translate()
>
> Esta transformación se caracteriza por un vector bidimensional. Sus coordenadas definen cuánto se mueve el elemento en cada dirección.

Ejemplo con la ayuda de

### Ejemplo:

```css
.caja0{/*transform: translate() con la posision relativa*/
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgb(238, 121, 36);
    
    transform: translate(100px);
    position:relative;
}
.caja1{/*transform: translate() sin posision relativa*/
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgb(99, 217, 20);
    transform: translate(100px);
}
.caja2{/*transform sin posision absolute*/
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgb(20, 122, 217);
    
    transform: translate(100px);
    position:absolute;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="caja0">
  caja0
</div>
<div class="caja1">
  caja1
</div>
<div class="caja2">
  caja2
</div>
```

Comment: veo que utiliza el margen para el posicionamiento verdad?

Comment: para mover un elemento y dejar el espacio como quien dice lleno usa `left` `top` `right` `button` y para mover un elemento y que repercute en los demas siendo relativos usa `margin`... espero te ayude

Answer (score 0):

cuando aplicas el Transform translate, el elemento ocupa la nueva posición mas el margen que tiene definido, ejemplo:
si tienes un `div` de ancho 50px y `margin` de 10px, ocuparías 10px a la izquierda 50px del elemento y 10px a la derecha, serian 70px, si lo trasladas a la derecha supón 10px, entonces el elemento seria el que se desplaza, dejando a la izquierda 10px que es lo que se desplaza , después 10px mas del margen izquierdo , y luego seguiría el elemento.

antes:

```
..10px..|.....50px el elemento...|..10px..
```

después trasladándolo 10px a la derecha

```
..10px del translate..|.10px margen izquierdo.|.50px el elemento..|.10px margen derecho..
```